# Webpack different installation commands

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, modular-design

What is the difference between:

> npm install webpack -g

and

> npm install -S webpack

What does the big S letter represent? Is it enough if I just install the webpack globally (first statement) or do I have to do the second line of code as well for my project? I couldn't find any clarification on Google for this. I'm familiar with the webpack concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-g` stands for "**g**lobal", which means that particular package not will be saved inside "node_modules" folder in actual working directory. Rather than that, it will be saved in your computer's central package repository, which is usually used by command-line npm application packages (like `webpack`).

`-S` (big "s") stands for "**s**ave", which install the package and saves metadata about it into project's `package.json` file. Later on, this file can be shipped with your source code via GIT repository to someone's else development environment. Then, dependency set can be "restored" by invoking `npm install` command.

Question for difference between those two actually makes sense. Many developers recommend to use locally (project-scoped) webpack rather than global version - one of main reasons is to make project independent from global webpack and its version, which may vary from user to user and always ship the code with particular webpack version saved in `package.json`.

Comment: so I can just use save instead of "big s" for instance: npm install --save react-redux. Also why "big s" since cmd-windows isn't case sensitive?

Comment: Windows cmd isn't case sensitive when it comes to dealing with filenames, but it matters when you pass arguments to the applications.